# react-router-redux: Mapping route params to state

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, redux, isomorphic-javascript

Is there a way to automatically map route parameters to state keys?

For example: I would like to initialize `state.auth.resetEmail` and `state.auth.resetToken` to the route parameters `params.resetEmail` `params.resetToken` whenever those route parameters are available.

Maybe im approaching this in the wrong way?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but as I am now starting with the same setup a year later I have the exact same question, would you mind sharing how to solve this (I am using Immutable.js)?